# Does $E[g(Y)|X]$ belong to $L^2(X)?$ ($g$: scalar function)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider two random vectors $X$ and $Y$ of respective size $p$ and $q$ with values in $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$. Let $g:\mathbb{R}^q\to\mathbb{R}$ be a scalar function. The result I'm looking at claims:

> The conditional expectation $E[g(Y)|X]$ is the orthogonal projection
>   in $L^2$ of $g(Y)$ $\color{blue}{\text{on the space $L^2(X)$ of square integrable
>  functions of $X$}}$.

(This is Property B.17 in Volume II of Gourieroux and Monfort (1996).) To someone who is familiar with the topic, do you think the text in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ above says that $E[g(Y)|X]\in L^2(X)$?

I tried to see it using Jensen's inequality and the convexity of $z\mapsto z^2$:
$$
E\Big\{\left(E[g(Y)|X]\right)^2\Big\}\geq\Big\{E[E[g(Y)|X]]\Big\}^2=\{E[g(Y)]\}^2.
$$
So even if $E[g(Y)]$ is finite, I still have the inequality in the wrong direction. This book isn't always completely rigorous, so there might be an implicit assumption somewhere. Can someone please clarify? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct statement is that if $g(Y) \in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, then $E[g(Y)|X] \in L^2(\Omega,\sigma(X),P) \subseteq L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and $E[g(Y)|X]$ is the orthogonal projection of $g(Y)$ onto $L^2(\Omega,\sigma(X),P)$.

See, e.g. Williams: *Probability with Martingales* section 9.4

Comment: Thanks. Can you please clarify the implication $g(Y)\in L^2\implies E[g(Y)|X]\in L^2$?

Comment: $E[E[g(Y)|X]^2] \leq E[E [g(Y)^2 | X]] = E[g(Y)^2] < \infty$ where the first inequality is given by conditional Jensen.